# JavaScript while (sentinel controlled loop) error

Tags: javascript

there is an error in the following code as it seems. Can't find the error of the code.
the rest of the program evaluates the value of the type of variable returnValueFinal as null. I want while loop to prompt the user to input a number, and the while loop is expected to work as a sentinel controlled loop. 
yet is doesn't work as expected. 
Here is my code,

```
while( typeof(returnValueFinal) === null )
                {
                    prompt("Please enter a number");
                    console.log("null value");
                }
```

can someone find the error? thanks in advance

Comment: `typeof(null) === 'object'` You want `returnValueFinal == null` (will also catch undefined)

Comment: It will be false in some browsers if you dont check for the string  of null too, on other occasions, it will not run because the browser will see that it is never going to exit the loop since you arent updating the value of `returnValueFinal` in any way for it to see that it has changed its type. Unless you have other code you arent showing us that is, in that case, ignore that point, this is just my initial thoughts, without more code/info, I cant comment more accurately. Browser to browser it will change but thats the 2 most likely reasons its not running as you expect.

Comment: Interesting. Which browsers?

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` returns a string

so `typeof(returnValueFinal) === null` returns false , in fact if 
`returnValueFinal` is null  use `returnValueFinal === null`

Comment: But `typeof({}) === 'object'`

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at @Wainage, thats going to evaluate to `true` because `{}` *is* an object.,

Comment: I'm saying `null` isn't the only thing that will make that condition true. If returnValueFinal = {} it will (per his code) announce "null"